# How To Load json Data To PivotTable.js in Mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, pivottable.js

I am using  **PivotTable.js**

Run-time error and I do not know what is

```
  [HttpGet]        
    public JsonResult  DataResult ()
    {
        List<jsonList> list = new List<jsonList>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            jsonList New = new jsonList();
            New.Age = i;
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                New.Gender = "Female";
            }
            else
            {
                New.Gender= "Male";

            }
            New.Name= i.ToString();
            New.Party = "NDP";
            New.Province= "Quebec";


            list.Add(New);
        }


        return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and  View
JavaScript code snippet at the bottom

```html
<link href="../../assets/PivotCss/pivot.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="output"></div>



<script src="~/scripts/Pivote/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/Pivote/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/Pivote/**pivot.js**"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
<script>



        $(document).ready(function () {

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "Get",
                url: "/ReportBuilder/DataResult",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: [],
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                    $("#output").pivot(
           JSON.stringify(data),
            {
                rows: ["Age"],
                cols: ["Province", "Party"]
            }
            );
                }
                });      
    });
   
</script>
```

And Alert Result Json 
[image]

And Firebug Error page 
[image]

This error is that when run
Thanks for your kindness

Comment: Add your code as text, not image, its easier for others to help you

Comment: Thank you for your attention

Comment: Just get rid of `JSON.stringify` ;)